# Click on UITextfield navigates back to previous view

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, segue

I have made an application in Swift for iOS with 2 view controllers in the same story board. I have connected both views using a segue. It navigates perfectly as wanted. In second view i have added two `UITextField`s and a `UIButton`. When I click on the textfield it kills the current view and goes back to the previous view. The button is clickable and behaves normally.

I have already checked the enable user interaction property for all.

[image: First page-Segue is linked to order now button]
[image: Second page-Problem with textfields]

Comment: have you implemented textfield's delegate method ?

Comment: @RichardG No i haven't. How is that done? Can you please tell me i am a beginner!

Comment: Can you provide some code in second ViewController?

Comment: I have written no code. The view controller is as it is. Do i need to add some code??